# sed paste below pattern string in variable

Tags: bash, variables, design-patterns, sed, matching

I am looking for a solution to paste a variable below a matching pattern
I have a half solution but cannot finish my script...
My aim with this script is to paste the variable "OSI" automatically below the correct Month.

```
/var/etc/osi.conf
    ###Jan###
    ###Feb###
    ###Mar###
    ###Apr###
    ###May###
    ###Jun###
    ###Jul###
    ###Aug###
    ###Sep###
    ###Oct###
    ###Nov###
    ###Dec###
```

Script:

```
    #!/bin/bash +x
    DATE=$(date | awk '{print $2}')
    DATE2=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "3 year")
    read -r -p "USERNAME: " USERNAME
    read -r -p "PASSWORD: " PASSWORD


    OSI="
    "$USERNAME"
    "$PASSWORD"
    "$DATE2"
    Fail 1
    eth0"

    sed -i 's/\#\#\#"$(date | awk '{print $2}')"\#\#\#/$OSI/g' /var/etc/osi.conf
```

///###EDITED###

Below you can find the result. Because the creation month is March and. Hence, the created user must be below ###Mar###

var/etc/osi.conf

```
###Jan###
###Feb###
###Mar###
"$USERNAME"
"$PASSWORD"
"$DATE2"
Fail 1
eth0"
###Apr###
###May###
###Jun###
###Jul###
###Aug###
###Sep###
###Oct###
###Nov###
###Dec###
```

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Can you give us a little more background on what it is you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My aim is to automatize one process. One person will enter credentials (username & password) and the script will automatically paste the username and password in the file var/etc/osi.conf below the correct month. The correct month is the month when the credentials are created from the user.

Comment: The office of secret intelligence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified, so I don't have to input some name, don't mess around in /etc, don't have issues with locale and date and keep osi.conf unchanged for testing:

```
DATE=$(LC_ALL=C date | awk '{print $2}')
DATE2=$(LC_ALL=C date +%Y-%m-%d -d "3 year")
USERNAME="Hein"
PASSWORD="53cr3t"

echo -e "$USERNAME\n$PASSWORD\n$DATE2\nFail 1\neth0" > tmp.txt

sed "/$DATE/rtmp.txt" osi.conf
```

Result:

```
###Jan###
###Feb###
###Mar###
Hein
53cr3t
2021-03-13
Fail 1
eth0
###Apr###
###May###
###Jun###
###Jul###
###Aug###
###Sep###
###Oct###
###Nov###
###Dec###
```

If you need quotes around some values, experiment with masking or read the reference.

The keypoint here is sed's ability (Gnu-sed) to r:=read a file and input it at a certain pattern or line number.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. But the script overwrites the first user in osi.conf if I will enter the second username. How can I avoid it? I want that all users be documented

Comment: To make the changes permanent, you have call sed with -i in the script. If I make this in my script, I can add multiple groups of line without overwriting something.